# Validation not working mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im using Monggose 4.8.1. I have a simple schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Organisation = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Organisation name must be provided'],
    unique: [true, 'Organisation name must be unique']
  },
  createdBy: { 
    type: String, 
    ref: 'User'
  },
  createdOn: {
    type: Date,
    "default": Date.now
  },
  availableUntil: {
    type: Date
  }
});

mongoose.model('Organisation', Organisation);
```

I've already saved the email email@domain.com in the document.

Now I want to try saving it again and first check that its valid using `validateAsync`. So i expect to get an error because the email is not unique.

```
var organisation = new Organisation({
    name: 'email@domain.com'
});

var validResult = organisation.validateSync();

console.log('validResult is ', validResult);
```

But validResult is always `undefined`...

**EDIT**

I added an extra attribute to my schema:

```
  eggs: {
    type: Number,
    min: [6, 'Too few eggs'],
    max: 12
  }
```

And then tried to save `eggs: 3` and this produced an error. So bizarrely, mongoose validation does not seem to check if a value is unique or not, even when set in the schema...

Comment: any update on this? i notice validateSync doesn't work with a few type validations nor does it work with custom validators

Answer (score 1):

For this type of validation you can follow this process using `path` and `validate`.

in schema

```
var OrganisationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Organisation name must be provided']
  }
 //....
});


OrganisationSchema.path('name').validate(function(value, done){
  var self = this;
  if(!self.isNew){
    return done(true);
  }else{
   //mongoose.models['Organisation'] or self.model('Organisation')
    mongoose.models['Organisation'].count({name: value}, function(err, count){
      if(err){
        return done(err);
      }

      return done(!count)
    });
  }
}, "This email already exists" );


mongoose.model('Organisation', OrganisationSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

Mark.

Could you verify that mongodb has record for your saved model: `db.organisations.find()`?

it looks like if you have `undefined` value it means the document had passed validation steps by following the documentation for `validateSync()`:

```
  var err = doc.validateSync();
  if ( err ){
    handleError( err );
  } else {
    // validation passed
  }
```